# What robot did I see at an archery trade show?

Tags: character-identification

A friend of mine spotted this character at an archery trade show. Neither of us can figure out if it's an established pop culture persona or just some company's mascot.

[image: Tall, shiny black robot with an orange hand]

Comment: Just tried Google image search.  Nothing with that distinctive emblem on its chest.

Comment: Which archery trade show was this? (Location, etc)?

Comment: @JohnP Archery Trade Association show in downtown Indianapolis.

Comment: The helmet, wrist, and knee pads have the same logo as a poster in the background. So it's probably a mascot for whatever that logo represents.

Comment: Poster in the background? I think you're looking at his backpack. But, yes, the over abundance of logos was why I suspected a mascot.

Comment: https://atatradeshow.org/2018/public/Exhibitors.aspx

Comment: As you can tell from the photo, this was near the Megamouth booth (5117), but I couldn't find a nearby vendor with this logo.

Comment: My first thought was [Hudzen 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Day_(Red_Dwarf)), though it's not really the same... https://pm1.narvii.com/6351/fa501acc49934def7aed18f477c144fb30c7f712_hq.jpg

Comment: @Aeryk Yeah, you're right. It seemed aligned with those green posters in the background. My mistake.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This appears to be the "OZ" robot designed by Robot Costumes USA for [ScentLok Technologies](https://www.google.co.uk/search?biw=1396&bih=624&ei=YAZhWryoG-HagAbNgo-wCg&q=ScentLok&oq=ScentLok&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0i67k1j0i20i263k1j0i67k1l2j0l2j0i10k1l2j0.2036.3173.0.3281.3.3.0.0.0.0.96.226.3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.221....0.EiSmfGVlawk)

You can see some [video footage](https://www.facebook.com/RobotCostumesUsa/videos/1481282985319049/) on their website. A closer inspection of the logo reveals that it says Active Odor Destroyer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: nice find! I couldn't find anything about the robot. Has my upvote :D

Comment: Based on the photo, I was trying to figure out what an "ACTIVE DOOR ESTROYFR" was.  What a great font choice!

Comment: Since the D and O are so close together, it got me wondering if it was saying "active door destroyer" instead. Does "estroyfr" come from damage to the letters?

Comment: @JohnDvorak - They illuminate. In this instance some of the bulbs appear to not be working very well.

Answer (score 12):

The character is in some way associated with **ScentLok**

https://www.scentlok.com/

[image]
<sub>(source: [scentlok.com](https://www.scentlok.com/wp-content/uploads/logo.png))</sub>

He appears to be sporting the ScentLok logo.

*Found by identifying the RexPID sign in the background, going to the [exhibitors floorplan](https://atatradeshow.org/2018/public/EventMap.aspx?ID=434&sortMenu=106000#), finding the RexPID booth and then looking at the vendors that seemed to be within line of sight of that booth*